# Facebook page is not opening with icon link - nightwatch

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, typescript, nightwatch.js

I´m new at using **Nightwatch.js**
I want to click on facebook icon and make it open in a new page.

How can I test if the icon link is clicked? Thanks.

```
module.exports = {
        "Facebook link" : function (browser) {
            browser
                .url(http://m.unitel.ao/fit/)
                .waitForElementVisible('.socal', 3000)
                .waitForElementPresent('.fa.fa-facebook', 15000)
                .useCss().click('.fa.fa-facebook')
                .pause(3000)
                .assert.urlContains('facebook')
                .end()}};
```

Anda whatt i get is this:

```
> Running:  Facebook link
         ? Element <.socal> was visible after 118 milliseconds. 
         ? Element <.fa.fa-facebook> was present after 21 milliseconds. 
         ? Testing if the URL contains "facebook".  - expected "facebook" but got: http: //m.unitel.ao/fit/
```

It´s not opening facebook page. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you get any errors or messages like element not found? And what is the html of the link being tested.

Comment: Hi Tedd, thanks for answering. When I run the test I get this message:  Running:  Facebook link
 ? Element <.bottom> was visible after 89 milliseconds.
 ? Element <#facebook> was present after 17 milliseconds.
 ? Testing if the URL contains "facebook".  - expected "facebook" but got: http:
//192.168.51.25/mychallenges.net/unitel-fit/